# When I want to "apt-get update" can not do that Err:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: ubuntu, server, updates

sudo apt-get update

reult is:

`

```
`
Err:118 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:119 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Fetched 1213 kB in 13s (90.4 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`
```

`

I'm new user to ubuntu
I wanted to "sudo apt-get update but I saw this problem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem like the server issue since the IP mentioned is working fine for me.
Try running the IP "185.125.190.36" from your browser. If you can't access it, it's possible the mirror is not available to you.

In that case, you just need to update the repo to something else.

Follow this guide to change the repo: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#:~:text=One%20method%20is%20to%20go,change%20settings%20in%20this%20window](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#:%7E:text=One%20method%20is%20to%20go,change%20settings%20in%20this%20window).

Let me know if this helps.